# Как загрузить данные из файла в переменную?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

#файл data.txt расположен на моем рабочем столе
dataset = np.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter=",")

X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
```

Comment: код расположен Jupiter notebook

Comment: поправьте вопрос, чтобы он реальную проблему показывал (с путём  к файлу)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/Dima/Desktop/data.txt", delimiter=",")
```

Comment: чего не хватало так это обратной косой черты backslash "/" вместо "\"

Comment: вы можете писать: `r'C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\data.txt'`